# How to calculate by column and stop at certain condition?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I have `dataframe` below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID':  ['27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '48002', '48002', '48002'],
        'Invoice_Date': ['2020-06-26', '2020-06-29', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-14', '2020-07-25', 
                         '2020-07-30', '2020-08-02', '2020-05-13', '2020-06-20', '2020-06-28'],
        'Payment_Term': [7,8,3,6,4,7,8,5,3,6],
        'Payment_Date': ['2020-07-05', '2020-07-05','2020-07-03', '2020-07-21', '2020-07-31', 
                         '2020-08-15', '2020-08-22', '2020-06-16', '2020-06-23', '2020-07-05'],
        })

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Invoice_Date', 'Payment_Term', 'Payment_Date'])

df['Invoice_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Invoice_Date'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['Payment_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Payment_Date'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['Due_Date'] = df['Invoice_Date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['Payment_Term'], unit = 'd') 
df['Delay'] = df['Payment_Date'] - df['Due_Date']
df['Delay'] = df['Delay'].dt.days                                                
df['diff'] = df.groupby('ID')['Invoice_Date'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
df['diff'] = df['diff'].fillna(0)
df
```

I need to make the `days` column to stop at 30 and start calculating new.
To make life difficult, the `days` should be calculated based on group by `ID`. I previously used:

```
df.loc[0, 'days'] = df.loc[0, 'diff']

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'days'] = df.loc[i-1, 'days'] + df.loc[i, 'diff']
    
print(df)
```

and thus the output:

```
      ID Invoice_Date  Payment_Term Payment_Date   Due_Date  Delay  diff  days
0  27459   2020-06-26             7   2020-07-05 2020-07-03      2   0.0   0.0
1  27459   2020-06-29             8   2020-07-05 2020-07-07     -2   3.0   3.0
2  27459   2020-06-30             3   2020-07-03 2020-07-03      0   1.0   4.0
3  27459   2020-07-14             6   2020-07-21 2020-07-20      1  14.0  18.0
4  27459   2020-07-25             4   2020-07-31 2020-07-29      2  11.0  29.0
5  27459   2020-07-30             7   2020-08-15 2020-08-06      9   5.0  34.0
6  27459   2020-08-02             8   2020-08-22 2020-08-10     12   3.0  37.0
7  48002   2020-05-13             5   2020-06-16 2020-05-18     29   0.0  37.0
8  48002   2020-06-20             3   2020-06-23 2020-06-23      0  38.0  75.0
9  48002   2020-06-28             6   2020-07-05 2020-07-04      1   8.0  83.0
```

**The result that I need is:**

```
      ID Invoice_Date  Payment_Term Payment_Date   Due_Date  Delay  diff  days
0  27459   2020-06-26             7   2020-07-05 2020-07-03      2   0.0   0.0
1  27459   2020-06-29             8   2020-07-05 2020-07-07     -2   3.0   3.0
2  27459   2020-06-30             3   2020-07-03 2020-07-03      0   1.0   4.0
3  27459   2020-07-14             6   2020-07-21 2020-07-20      1  14.0  18.0
4  27459   2020-07-25             4   2020-07-31 2020-07-29      2  11.0  29.0
5  27459   2020-07-30             7   2020-08-15 2020-08-06      9   5.0   0.0
6  27459   2020-08-02             8   2020-08-22 2020-08-10     12   3.0   8.0
7  48002   2020-05-13             5   2020-06-16 2020-05-18     29   0.0   0.0
8  48002   2020-06-20             3   2020-06-23 2020-06-23      0  38.0   0.0
9  48002   2020-06-28             6   2020-07-05 2020-07-04      1   8.0   0.0
```

The difference is the summation of days in line 4 stop because when it add to next row it would be greater than 30. So, it start new calculation at line 5.

Comment: all you have to do is add two flags to check if id is same as above row and to check if value is less than 30. add these flags to your loop. if flag is false, then calculation restarts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still doesn't catch the exact output you're looking for because some corresponding diff values are greater than 30 even without the sum (e.g. index 8), so they'll remain on data.

```
def func(x):
    x = x.values
    values = [x[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(x)):
        value = values[i-1] + x[i]
        values.append(value if value < 30 else x[i])
    return values

df['days'] = df.groupby("ID")["diff"].transform(func)
print(df[['ID', 'diff', 'days']])
```

Output:

```
      ID  diff  days
0  27459   0.0   0.0
1  27459   3.0   3.0
2  27459   1.0   4.0
3  27459  14.0  18.0
4  27459  11.0  29.0
5  27459   5.0   5.0
6  27459   3.0   8.0
7  48002   0.0   0.0
8  48002  38.0  38.0
9  48002   8.0   8.0
```

---

**Edit:**

Changing the function definition should work:

```
def func(x):
    x = x.values
    values = [x[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(x)):
        value = values[i-1] + x[i]
        if value < 30:
            values.append(value)
        elif x[i] >= 30:
            values.append(x[i-1])
        else:
            values.append(x[i])
    return values

df['days'] = df.groupby("ID")["diff"].transform(func)
print(df[['ID', 'diff', 'days']])

      ID  diff  days
0  27459   0.0   0.0
1  27459   3.0   3.0
2  27459   1.0   4.0
3  27459  14.0  18.0
4  27459  11.0  29.0
5  27459   5.0   5.0
6  27459   3.0   8.0
7  48002   0.0   0.0
8  48002  38.0   0.0
9  48002   8.0   8.0
```

Comment: Hi @Cainã Max Couto-Silva. This code works wonderfully. But, on line 8 it should be starting new calculation as it exceed 30 days.

Comment: I've added a modified function in the edited answer. It should work, but make sure it makes sense for your data/analysis.